# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send' in my discord.py main.py code

Tags: python, discord, bots

When I try to send a message using the channel.send() feature in discord.py, I am handed an error. 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
Please help!

In these lines of code:

```
 channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
    channel.send('hi')
```

it's supposed to just work
but it don't

Comment: Why does `get_channel` return `None`? Have you looked at the documentation for the library to understand that?

Comment: please provide a full example of your code

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `get_channel` returns `None`. I'm thinking of two (three) possible reasons for that:

- The `channel_id` is false, ie. does not exist
- `get_channel` only looks at cached channels, maybe the channel is not cached for some reason. You could try `fetch_channel` instead.
- I'm not very sure about this one, but it could be that the bot's user is not member of the guild and its only an application (not sure if it's a prerequisite to have a user in the guild to see the channels)